# How to count the number of total chars in const char**?

Tags: c++, pointers, char, constants

I am attempting to write a Vulkan application from scratch, and I have been having issues with attempting to count the total number of characters in a

```
const char**
```

I was wondering how I could iterate through each character of each "c string".
This is for the purpose of comparing existing instance extensions for creating a Vulkan instance.

This is the function I'm having issues with and every problem seems localized to the fact that sizeof gives back the size in bytes, not the number of elements.

```
void Extensions_Manager::GetInstanceExtensionNames(const char** extNames, const char** glfwNames, bool validation)
{
std::string extension = "";

if (validation)
    instanceExtensionNames.push_back(VK_EXT_DEBUG_UTILS_EXTENSION_NAME);


for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(glfwNames); ++i)
{
    if (glfwNames[i] == '\0')
    {
        instanceExtensionNames.push_back(extension.c_str());

        slog("Instance extension to use %s", extension.c_str());

        extension = "";
    }
    else
    {
        extension += glfwNames[i];
    }
}

for (const char* ext : instanceExtensionNames)
{
    slog("Available Extension: %s", ext);
}

extNames = instanceExtensionNames.data();
}
```

```
instanceExtensionNames
```

is a static vector of const char*

Comment: `sizeof(glfwNames)` doesn't do what you think it does. It's a size of the pointer, not related to the actual number of elements in the array.

Comment: In C++ the solution is to use vectors and strings.

Comment: `strlen` is your friend for the number of characters in each `char*`, or C-string. If you can guarantee the array of C-strings is null-terminated, you can then just iterate over the array until you get to `NULL`.

Comment: I mentioned in my post that I realized that sizeof is memory space in bytes not an element count, I was wondering how to iterate through a const char** so I can see if an instance extension is already in glfwNames.\

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < strlen(glfwNames); ++i)`.

Comment: That's not right, if it were just a char* then that would would be fine.

Comment: `sizeof(glfwNames)` returns the size of the type `glfwNames` which is the size of a `char **`, a pointer which, although dependent on the platform, is probably 8 bytes on a 64 bit machine.

Comment: @samuelnj Again, I've mentioned that I already know this.

Comment: No one is going to be able to answer that, you haven't provided the information. Think about how you know you've reached the end of a c-string : when you reach `\0`. So logically you need a way to know you've reached the valid end of a pointer  to pointers. To me it seems like that's either by some size parameter you pass to the function or when you reach a `NULL`. You haven't specified either.

Comment: The size is what I'm attempting to deduce. I have no way of knowing how many extensions are going to be present on what architecture. I need to figure out how many extensions I have total by somehow getting through that const char**.

Comment: @IanRosenberg -- You can only determine the end by some agreement between your code and the client calling your code.  Whether that is two consecutive null strings, or some other scheme, that's an agreement on what interface to use between the function being called and the function caller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to count the number of total chars in const char**

Loop over each string in the pointed array. For each string, count the number of chars. Add the lengths together.

Note that you may want to consider whether you want to count the number of `char` objects (i.e. code-units), or the number of character symbols which are not necessarily the same number depending on the character encoding.

> ```
> sizeof(glfwNames)
> ```

`sizeof` has nothing to do with "number of elements". `glfwNames` is a pointer. `sizeof(glfwNames)` is the size of a pointer object. All pointers of particular type are always the same size (within a particular system) regardless of the object they point at.

There is no way of finding out the number of elements if given only a pointer to an element of the array and no other information. It is simply not possible because a pointer doesn't contain the necessary information. Without knowing when to stop iterating the array, there is no way to do the iteration correctly.

These are common ways of iterating a range (the range being an array in this case) of iterators (pointers being iterators for arrays):

- Pass the length of the range as an argument, and use an indexed loop. This works with randomly accessible iterators such as pointers.
- Pass an iterator (pointer in this case) to the end (one past the last element) of the range. This approach is more generic as it works with non-random access iterators as well. Increment the iterator in the loop, and once it equals to the end, you know what you've reached.
- Designate certain value as a sentinel element (also known as a terminator). When a sentinel value is encountered, you know that iteration has reached the end of the range. This approach is used with null-terminated strings.
- <sub>A side note: Interestingly, the command line arguments (`argc` + `argv`) provide both ways: `argc` is the length, but the `char** argv` is also terminated by a null pointer.</sub>

If you receive `glfwNames` from a library, then consult the documentation of the library for how to find out the length. If you're in control of both calling and defining the function, then make sure that you pass sufficient information into the function.